# Ruby on Rails: Two Models Both Have Has/Many and Belongs_to

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I've recently inherited an older rails application which has a model called `Package`. One of the tasks is to be able to allow Packages to be deleted. However, that's not currently possible, due to the way the `PackageState` and `Package` models are setup. Here's an example:

Package Model:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package_state, class_name: 'PackageState', foreign_key: :package_state_id
  has_many :package_states
end
```

And the PackageState:

```
class PackageState < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packages, :class_name => 'Package'
end
```

What would be the best way to go about reorganizing

Comment: *"that's not currently possible, due to the way the PackageState and Package models are setup"* - what, exactly, is the problem/question? Are you getting errors when you attempt to delete? If so, what are they? If not, what is the current behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is a one-way [has_and_belong_to_many (HABTM) association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) between `Package` and `PackageState`, which would look like this:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :package_states
end

class PackageState < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :packages
end
```

The accepted answer from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026196/can-i-have-a-one-way-habtm-relationship) has this excerpt about one-way HABTM associations:

> Functionally yes, but semantically no. Using HABTM in a "one-sided" fashion will achieve exactly what you want. The name HABTM does unfortunately insinuate a reciprocal relationship that isn't always the case. Similarly, belongs_to :foo makes little intuitive sense here.
>
> Don't get caught up in the semantics of HABTM and the other association, instead just consider where your IDs need to sit in order to query the data appropriately and efficiently. Remember, efficiency considerations should above all account for your productivity.

You also stated that

> that's not currently possible, due to the way the `PackageState` and `Package` models are setup

but that is just not correct. There is nothing stopping you from getting a package object using `ActiveRecord` and calling `destroy` on it.

You should ask yourself how you intend to use both models (particularly when it comes to deleting packages) and determine which association would work best. Considering this is an inherited application, you will likely need to deal with legacy data, but that's a topic for another day.